# Slider module and extending it further

Tags: javascript, modules

I created this module, and I'm wondering if I did a good job. How would an experienced JavaScript developer improve this simple slider module further? Like, let's say that you want to use this module on 3 sliders on the same page.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/W9rEu) is a jsFiddle.

**Module**

```
var sliderTest = (function(){
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ✚   private variables
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/    
    var expoElement = document.querySelector(".test")
    var expoCanvas = expoElement.querySelector(".canvas")
    var expoSlides = expoCanvas.querySelectorAll(".slide")
    var controlPrev = expoElement.querySelector(".control.prev")
    var controlNext = expoElement.querySelector(".control.next")
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ✚   private functions
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/   
    function whereIsActive(){
       var y = {}
       for(var i = 0; i < expoSlides.length; i++){
          if(expoSlides[i].classList.contains("active")){
              y.current = i;
              if(expoSlides[i+1]){
                  y.next = i+1;
              } else {
                  y.next = 0;
              }

              if(expoSlides[i-1]){
                  y.prev = i-1;
              } else {
                  y.prev = expoSlides.length-1;
              }                   
          }       
      }   
      return y
   }

   function removeActiveClasses(){
       for(var i = 0; i < expoSlides.length; i++){
           expoSlides[i].classList.remove("active")
       }       
   }   
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ✚   public methodes
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/

        var publicMethod = {
            nextSlide:function(ev){
               ev.preventDefault();
               var nextIndex = whereIsActive().next;
               removeActiveClasses();
               expoSlides[nextIndex].classList.add("active");          
       },

       prevSlide:function(ev){
           ev.preventDefault();
           var prevIndex = whereIsActive().prev;

           removeActiveClasses();
           expoSlides[prevIndex].classList.add("active")
      },
      sendInTheClone:function(){alert(whereIsActive().current)}
  }
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ✚   event listners
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/

            controlNext.addEventListener("click", publicMethod.nextSlide)
            controlPrev.addEventListener("click", publicMethod.prevSlide)    
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ✚   return
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/

        return publicMethod;
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">

    <div class="canvas">
        <div class="slide ">1</div>
        <div class="slide ">2</div>     
        <div class="slide active">3</div>
        <div class="slide ">4</div>
    </div>

    <a class="control prev" href="" data-control="prev">prev</a> <a class="control next" href="" data-control="next">next</a>

</div>
```

Comment: your comments and white space are very distracting.

Comment: Agreed about the whitespace, it makes it much harder to read the code.
I tried adding this to jsFiddle and it didn't work. I assume it does?

Comment: @kevnius, please provide a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of this code so we can test it out.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W9rEu/

Comment: Why are the comments distracting? I just divided the script into it's logical parts (private variables, private functions, public methods, event listeners, return statement).

Comment: @kevinius The comments are distracting because comments  generally are not read unless the code doesn't make sense. We are trying to review the code, and the comments are essentially noise. Much worse is all the whitespace. Adding an additional line between each line requires a lot of vertical scrolling and is really excessive if the line is just `}`. Also FYI, your fiddle doesn't work in my browser: IE 9

Comment: The script doesn't work in <IE10 because i'm using the element.classList API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `document.querySelector`

While it is a great function to use, you are using in the wrong situations.

For every time you use it, you are getting an array of elements with a class that you passed in to the function. Why not just use `document.getElementsByClassName`?

Sure, it takes a little bit longer to type but it's faster.

This about it: the `querySelector` function has to read the argument passed in and, based on it's syntax ('.' for classes, '#' for ids, and a few more), scan the document in a way unique to each type of identification (id, class, etc).

Wouldn't it be easier for the function to know that it was going to look for one class and for one class only?

## Semicolons

They aren't entirely necessary, and the interpreter probably adds them in for you, but your code looks like JavaScript when you put them in (at least in my opinion).

## HTML indentation

Your `div`s are perfectly indented, but when you go down to your `a`s, you start to try and clump them on to one line.

Originally, when I was looking at the `a` tag(s), I thought it was one really long `a` tag.

## JavaScript indentation

For the most part, it's really good. But there is one section that is bothering me: your `public methods` section.

I actually had to post this in to JSFiddle and click "Tidy up" to understand what was going on there.

I believe the problem is the closing bracket of `nextSlide`; it is too far back, and it looks like it is closing `publicMethod`.

## Built in output

In the `sendInTheClone` method of `publicMethod`, it uses the function `alert`.

Not everyone using this module may want an alert popping up on their screen; maybe they want it written to the DOM, or maybe they use custom pop-up boxes.

(Excuse this section ("Built in output") if I misunderstood your `sendInTheClone` function)

## Good things:

1. Contrary to what people have been commenting, I think that the big comments going across your code to split it up is a good idea. In my opinion, it helps with legibility.
2. The use of `publicMethod`. It's a pretty good idea; I like it.